# Docker-compose para criar lamp com phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, docker, phpunit

Estou tentando usar o docker-compose para criar um ambiente LAMP junto com o phpunit para rodar TDD php e o que pretendo fazer é o seguinte:

- rodar uma imagem mysql 5;
- rodar uma imagem phpunit 5;
- rodar uma imagem php 5.6 de forma que ele se comunique com as outras imagens;
- Executar pelo browser os sistemas php e poder rodar em um terminal os testes usando o phpunit;

Meu docker-compose esta assim:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lamp-teste

  php-unit:
      image: phpunit/phpunit:5.7.12

  php-5.6:
    image: php:5.6
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./log/apache2/error.log:/var/log/apache2/error.log
      - ./log/apache2/access.log:/var/log/apache2/access.log
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php-unit
```

Depois de executar o arquivo com o comando docker-compose up -d aparece isso:

```
Recreating dockerlampteste_mysql_1 ... 
Recreating dockerlampteste_php-unit_1 ... 
Recreating dockerlampteste_php-unit_1
Recreating dockerlampteste_mysql_1 ... done
Recreating dockerlampteste_php-5.6_1 ... 
Recreating dockerlampteste_php-5.6_1 ... done
```

E ao executar o comando "docker-compose ps" aparece isso:

```
Name                         Command             State     Ports  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
dockerlampteste_mysql_1      docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Up       
3306/tcp
dockerlampteste_php-5.6_1    docker-php-entrypoint php -a    Exit 0           

dockerlampteste_php-unit_1   /usr/local/bin/phpunit --help   Exit 0
```

E ao executar o comando "docker ps" aparece que apenas a imagem mysql esta sendo executada.

Pelo visto só o mysql esta rodando e o php e phpunit não, o que esta errado e como posso depois de executar tudo executar o phpunit pelo terminal ?

Comment: Amigo tente ver o motivo do container estar sendo finalizado, tente `docker logs dockerlampteste_php-5.6_1` e `docker logs dockerlampteste_php-5.6_1`. Eu sugeriria também colocar nomes para os containeres para facilitar o trabalho, veja um modelo bacana aqui: https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

Comment: Executei o log, apareceu essa msg: (21)Is a directory: AH00091: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Tenho que setar um local para os logs ? Como faço ?

Comment: remova seus volumes de logs e tente novamente: `      - ./log/apache2/error.log:/var/log/apache2/error.log
      - ./log/apache2/access.log:/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: Tentei sem os logs e deu erro, tentei setando apenas o diretorio para os logs e continuava na mesmo, resolvi mudar a imagem do php para php:5.6-apache e deu certo.

Comment: ah sim a php:5.6 usa nginx. blz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterei a imagem do php e o volume para logs do apache, ficando assim o docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lamp-teste

  php-unit:
      image: phpunit/phpunit:5.7.12

  php-5.6:
    image: php:5.6-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./log/apache2:/var/log/apache2
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php-unit
```